# MVC 4 Notification Messages to the User

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using a *controller - service - repository layer pattern* I'm my Application. The repository holds basic CRUD operations and the service layer all the business logic while the controllers are kept very lean (they only call the service layer functions).

I want to send messages (success, warning, etc.) to the user but I'm unsure how to do it from a **service layer** level? I've looked up some solutions using TempData and a base class but those only seem to work on a controller level.

Is there a good solution to push user notifications to a view from a service layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a good separation of concerns in your app architecture. It would be very wise to keep it this way - do not make your service layer to know anything about UI.

What I would do I would create some class for service layer to return as execution result.

```
public class ExecutionResult<T>
{
    public T Result { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

This way you could pass `Message` to `ViewBag.UserNotification` and shouw it in your view:

**Edit:** sample usage:

```
public class Math
{
    public ExecutionResult<double> Divide(double number, double divideBy)
    {
        if (divideBy == 0)
        {
            return new ExecutionResult<double>
                {
                    Result = double.NaN,
                    Message = "Division by zero is not possible"
                };
        }

        return new ExecutionResult<double>
            {
                Result = number/divideBy
            };
    }
}
```

This is just a sample. In real world you would take different approach in [comparing values of type `double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya2zha7s.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your idea, could you please give an example how i would use this approach in a function on the service layer level?

Comment: For an example of how this is used, see how Entity Framework uses DbEntityValidationResult here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.validation.dbentityvalidationresult(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 0):

With that kind of pattern you don't want to interact with the views directly from the service layer so you might consider returning some custom data transfer objects to the controller on each method call. These DTO's could contain any error messages or notifications. Then the controller can pass this data on to the view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how would I manage to show a message after an `Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Event")` call?

Comment: RedirectToAction has overloads that accept "routeValues". These can be any data you would like, in this case being your custom DTO.

Answer (score 0):

One way might be for your service methods to return boolean values to indicate the success or failure. The controller would then know this and can act accordingly.

Another way might be for methods to return a custom "Error" object that contains information about what happened in the service.