# how to hide or show links based not only on roles but other business logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

My MVC application has a handful of roles. ex Admin,General. I use a CustomRoleProvider but then in the view I do following

```
@if (Roles.IsUserInRole("admin"))
    {
        <div class="editor-label">@Html.RadioButton("selection", "View Project Details", false)View Project Details</div>
    }
```

Recently I was told to additionally restrict access based on business logic ex. if createdby user on a Project was 'xyz',allow 'xyz' access to the link. 
I know one way would be to check the controller and return different views based on the Roles and BusinessLogic. Thats going to be unmanageable!!
is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just store permissions in your model or in ViewBag and use if statements as above. You can also create method like `IsInBuissnesRole` and implement logic inside it.

Comment: where should I create this method? In the Role Provider?

Comment: Role provider is a good place. But also you can implement it in base controler

Answer (score 0):

I have answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475974/mvc-4-notification-messages-to-the-user/16476054#16476054).

Basically you should use viewmodel with properties denoting if certain features of the view should be enabled/visible to user. Then it is controller (maybe based onr some business logic service) should set these values.

Example:

```
// Model
public class Procuct
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}


// Viewmodel
public class ProcuctViewModel
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public bool CanEdit {get;set;}
  public bool CanDelete {get; set;}
}

// somewhere in controller
var product = new ProductViewModel(_repo.GetProductById(1));
if (Roles.IsUserInRole("admin"))
{
  product.CanEdit = true;
}
// ...
return View(product);
```

Then your view gets simpler and all the security stuff is moved to controller and is unittestable